# Materialize CSS SideNav

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, materialize

Okay i'm trying to use the mobile side navigation that materialize has built in and i'm able to get the menu icon to appear but then when i click it nothing happens, it's as if the function is not being called but there are not any errors in the console

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav class="white">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="index.html" class="brand-logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo" height="64"></a>
        <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons black-text">menu</i></a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a id="nav" href="index.html" class="red-text1">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="webdesign.html" class="red-text1">Web Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="graphicdesign.html" class="red-text1">Graphic Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="video.html" class="red-text1">Video</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html" class="red-text1">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="awards.html" class="red-text1">Awards</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html" class="red-text1">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
            <li><a href="index.html" class="red-text1">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="webdesign.html" class="red-text1">Web Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="graphicdesign.html" class="red-text1">Graphic Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="video.html" class="red-text1">Video</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html" class="red-text1">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="awards.html" class="red-text1">Awards</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html" class="red-text1">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<!-- Scripts-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://materializecss.com/templates/starter-template/js/init.js"></script>
```

I'm also using angular to build the page if that makes any difference

Comment: You have to initialize sidenav by `$(".button-collapse").sideNav();`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with angular. Angular don't support jquery and you have to make some adjustment according to it.
Delete init.js file.

In **main.ts** import
`import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';`

declare variable:
`declare var jQuery: any;`

implement your class with **OnInit** add following code:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
 constructor(private el:ElementRef){}
  ngOnInit() {
    jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).find('.button-collapse').sideNav();
  }
} `
```

For more info watch [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrdHEBkGAow)

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yYdpcmQRNWmpvJFVdLgO?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the initialization of the Navbar

```
$(".button-collapse").sideNav();
```

at least in your init.js

I had the same problem, but this little change fixed it.